# Is there a preferred or required way to sound shevarim?

Tags: halacha, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar, hearing

I have heard the *shevarim* sound from the shofar done in one of two ways:

- three short blasts maintaining the same pitch (like "toot-toot-toot")
- three short blasts alternating in pitch staring with a low pitch, becoming a high pitch and returning to the low pitch again (like "to-WHO-to; to-WHO-to; to-WHO-to". The middle part on a higher pitch.)

Is only one method correct, or either one? Is one method more preferable? Any sources to support the different styles?

Comment: If memory serves the latter reflect Galician practice. I don't know if you are limiting the question to these, but IIRC, the ancient Geonic practice preserved by the Yemenites, has one long that rises and falls (kind of like an air raid siren).

Comment: @mevaqesh I started researching a bit, and found something discussing the Yemenite practice. I may have something to formulate an answer with some reasoning why there are different customs. It seem that this originates from the various interpretations of the Torah term "teru'ah" from which the shevarim sound eventually emanated.

Comment: See the MB in hilchos Shofar.